# Changing Css From Array Value

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I know in Angular you can dynamically add a class to the element but how do I change the value of a property? I want each button to be the next spotColour of the array. I feel like my example explains it well:

```
<button style="background-color: arrThemes[0]['spotColour']"></button>
<button style="background-color: arrThemes[1]['spotColour']"></button>
<button style="background-color: arrThemes[2]['spotColour']"></button>

arrThemes = [
  {spotColour : 'rgb(238, 68, 136)', baseColour : 'rgb(80, 54, 78)'},
  {spotColour : 'rgb(179, 165, 136)', baseColour : 'rgb(88, 67, 59)'},
  {spotColour : 'rgb(87, 167, 82)', baseColour : 'rgb(47, 68, 46)'},
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ngStyle` tag to dynamically add styles

```
<button *ngFor="let item of arrThemes " [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.spotColour }"></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this expression with

```
<button style="{{ 'background-color: ' + arrThemes[0]['spotColour'] }}"></button>
```

or in more civil way using [**NgStyle**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

```
<button [ngStyle]="{'background-color': arrThemes[0]['spotColour']}"></button>
```

Comment: Try another variant. Also I have edited the first one. Try again

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) angular directive for that.

like below

`<button [ngStyle]="{'background-color': arrThemes[0]['spotColour']}"></button>`

Comment: Please add examples instead of just referring to documentations